# fixed html divs going over the edge

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to learn basic html&css and I was making a simple webpage with a navbar, but when I fix my header it goes over right side of the page.

```
<div ID="header">
    <table ID="navbar">
        <tr>
            <td>Home</td>
            <td>About</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>


#header {
background-color: yellow;
position: fixed;
height: 35px;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 2px solid red}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to align the nav center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define spacing for left and right.

here i made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yq6zoyhk/

```
#header {
background-color: yellow;
box-sizing: border-box;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 35px;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 2px solid red}
```

Answer (score 1):

add below css:

```
#header{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

box-sizing: border-box means that the width (100%) will contain border. Otherwise width of element would be 100% + 4px - and that is wider than your browser window

You may also get sick of default margin & padding setting in browsers, so i recommend to add:

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

at the beggining of css file if you haven't already done this

Answer (score 1):

Your Html file is correct but change in Css file.
CSS:

```
#header {background-color: yellow;position: fixed;height: 35px;width: 100%;border-radius: 10px;box-sizing: border-box;top: 0;left: 0;}
```

Past above code in your css file.

Here you can see working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Deep7/7fg3xcbo/2/).☺

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `position:fixed` you need to define the spacing from left and top, if you want it from left, add `left:0; top:0;` or if you want to center it then add `left:0; right:0; top:0;`